# Python json prase ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: python, json, string, python-2.7, gps

I'm acctually having trouble with an json string an python. I've written a script that use find-my-iphone python module this module give me this string at the output

> {u'locationType': u'', u'altitude': 0.0, u'locationFinished': True, u'longitude': 7.340714223689717, u'positionType': u'GPS', u'floorLevel': 0, u'timeStamp': 1497518502892L, u'latitude': 47.81268700030429, u'isOld': False, u'isInaccurate': False, u'verticalAccuracy': 0.0, u'horizontalAccuracy': 50.0}

After a bit of prosesing with:

```
loc = api.devices[deviceID].location()
locstr = str(loc).replace("u'",'"').replace("'",'"') #.replace("}","")
```

I obtain a string that look like this:

> {"locationType": "", "altitude": 0.0, "locationFinished": False, "longitude": 7.340450948111099, "positionType": "GPS", "floorLevel": 0, "timeStamp": 1497518436368L, "latitude": 47.81275740829093, "isOld": False, "isInaccurate": False, "verticalAccuracy": 0.0, "horizontalAccuracy": 100.0}

There is my code: 
`

```
from pyicloud import PyiCloudService
from geopy.distance import vincenty
import json
import sys

api = PyiCloudService('*****.*****@free.fr','******')
deviceID = u"Qo+Jyvct3IIl7N3MXrz6LfDvm8qjDCHjkedOvse1mhzWf1sikvSFQOHYVNSUzmWV"          # Needed
deviceNAME = "<AppleDevice(iPhone 5s: David Smartphone)>"                               # Just an help

api.devices[deviceID].location()
api.devices[deviceID].status()

loc = api.devices[deviceID].location()
locstr = str(loc).replace("u'",'"').replace("'",'"') #.replace("}","")
```

But when I try to use

`json.loads(locstr)`

Python give me :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "distancePAPA.py", line 19,
>   in 
>       t = json.loads(locstr)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/**init**.py", line 339, in loads
>       return _default_decoder.decode(s)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
>       obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
>       raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded") ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

I don't really know what I did wrong so I'am asking fo help

PS1: I just really need gps coordinate
PS2: I'm french so sorry for mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json

>>> loc = api.devices[deviceID].location()
>>> locstr = json.dumps(loc)
'{"horizontalAccuracy": 50.0, "floorLevel": 0, "isOld": false, "isInaccurate": false, "verticalAccuracy": 0.0, "timeStamp": 1497518502892, "altitude": 0.0, "locationFinished": true, "longitude": 7.340714223689717, "positionType": "GPS", "locationType": "", "latitude": 47.81268700030429}'

>>> json.loads(locstr)
{u'timeStamp': 1497518502892, u'altitude': 0.0, u'locationFinished': True, u'longitude': 7.340714223689717, u'horizontalAccuracy': 50.0, u'floorLevel': 0, u'locationType': u'', u'latitude': 47.81268700030429, u'isOld': False, u'isInaccurate': False, u'verticalAccuracy': 0.0, u'positionType': u'GPS'}
```

Comment: Thank for your solution I finnaly use your's

Answer (score 0):

Hi use the module **ast**,

`import ast
loc_str = ast.literal_eval(str(loc))`

Answer (score 0):

Json does not support `False` and the postfix `L` in `1497518436368L`; To make it regular, we need to convert it again

```
s = locstr.replace('False', 'false').replace('L,', ',')
```

And now, we could use `json.loads(s)`